# Angular 4 ngModel not working with checkbox inside multiple for loop

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am relatively new to Angular, I am unable to find out where I'm going wrong ?

Inside my component.html file, below section is working **absolutely fine**. It's checking only the applicable checkboxes.

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories;let i=index">
 <div class="col-xs-2 catStyle">
   <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="catIdList[i]" value="{{category._id}}" >  
          {{category.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here categories array having all the categories which I'm getting from sever. and catIdList array having list of previously selected categories which I want to precheck at the time of loading the page.

**But**

It's **not working** for the code below. It's checking all the checkboxes.

```
 <div *ngFor="let category of mapCat">
     <div *ngFor="let sc of category.subcat;let j=index">
         <div class="col-xs-2 subcatStyle">
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="subcatIdList[j]" value="{{sc._id}}" >  
     {{sc.name}}<hr style="margin: 4px 11px;"><p style="font-weight: 400;font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 0px;" >{{category.parentCatName}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

> The structure of mapCat is
>
> [{parentCatName: "XXXX", subcat: [{_id:
>   "5b17ef169a194e0ee8cfc276", parentRef: "5b17ecfe9a194e0ee8cfc275",
>   name: "YYY"}]}]

Comment: I supouse you need a multidimensional array and use subcatidList[i][j]. For use a multidimensional array remember, when you get the mapCat, create the array mapCat.forEach((c,index)=>{this.subcatidList[index]=[])

Comment: `It's checking all the checkboxes` -> Probably you need to look into your data which is getting assigned to the controls. Take a look through `Browser's inspeact element` option.

Comment: @RajeshKdev : I checked the value of ckeckboxes. For instance          <input  type="checkbox" value="5b8541bbbbcae90840939bcc" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-model="5b17ef169a194e0ee8cfc276"> ,so here ng-reflect-model and checkbox value is not same still its getting checked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've imported FormModule in '/app.module.ts'
      `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';@NgModule({imports: [FormsModule]})`

Bcoz,ngModel resides inside the Form module

Comment: not, the problem is that subcatIdList[j] is "something", (really an array), so always is checked the input

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div *ngFor="let category of mapCat">
 <div *ngFor="let sc of category.subcat;let j=index">
     <div class="col-xs-2 subcatStyle">
        <input type="checkbox" (click)="onCheck(sc.id,$event)" value="{{sc._id}}" >  
 {{sc.name}}<hr style="margin: 4px 11px;"><p style="font-weight: 400;font-size: 12px;margin-bottom: 0px;" >{{category.parentCatName}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

> Use this in your html
>
> Do not use ngModel inside checkbox

```
onCheck(service: any, event) {
  console.log(service, event, "Selected");
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.usecheckboxDatahere.push(service);     
  } else if (!event.target.checked) {
    let index = this."usecheckboxDatahere".indexOf(service);
    this.usecheckboxDatahere.splice(index, 1);
  }
  console.log(this.usecheckboxDatahere);     
}
```